# Jenkins git plugin How can I combine all git build data in a single item in the build sidebar

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have a scripted jenkinsfile that checks out multiple repos.

[image]

The sidebar of the build page fills up with a lot of "Git Build Data" items.

I'd like to combine all these items into a single "Git build info".

Is that possible ?
Can the sidebar be a tree structure ?
Can I manipulate the contents of the sidebar ?

I do not want to lose the info, I'd just like it to be less prominant.

I tried searching for solutions, but I'm not even sure which search terms I need to use.

Some snippets from my jenkinsfile

```
            stage('Extract') {
                parallel 'Extract': {
                    repos.each { myRepo -> 
                        if (myRepo.active) {
                            gitCheckout(
                                dir:"${config.applroot}/${myRepo.workspacePath}",
                                credentialsId: "${myRepo.credentialId}",
                                branch:"${myRepo.branch}",
                                url: "${myRepo.url}"
                                )
                        }
                    } // repos.each
                }
            } // Extract
```

gitCheckout in shared library

```
def call(Map config = [:]) {

    dir("${config.dir}") {
        print "Checkout ${config.dir} config.branch=${config.branch} url=${config.url} credentials=${config.credentialsId}"
        git branch:"${config.branch}", credentialsId: "${config.credentialsId}", url: "${config.url}"
    }
}
```